# Invalid argument error while decoding a JSON file in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode a JSON file using PHP. This is the Code that I am using.

```
<?php
  $content =  file_get_contents('result.json');

  $contendecoded = json_decode($content);

  print_r($contendecoded);

  foreach ($contendecoded as $each) {
    # code...
    echo '<li>' .$each->Receiver. '</li>';
  }
  ?>
```

This is the result.json file

```
{"Sender":"254705537065","Receiver":"7528452889","Amount":"1","FName":"Martinique","AccessToken":"8XRTHN59NCHvUGAASGbK6IcCzYcn"},
{"Sender":"254705537065","Receiver":"6584238686","Amount":"2","FName":"Phillipines2","AccessToken":"O4wBFWPmFA8ayKGYahhpdCAW97mg"},
{"Sender":"254705537065","Receiver":"6584238686","Amount":"2","FName":"Phillipines2","AccessToken":"O4wBFWPmFA8ayKGYahhpdCAW97mg"},
{"Sender":"254705537065","Receiver":"6584238686","Amount":"36","FName":"Phillipines3","AccessToken":"O4wBFWPmFA8ayKGYahhpdCAW97mg"},
{"Sender":"254705537065","Receiver":"6584238686","Amount":"36","FName":"Phillipines3","AccessToken":"O4wBFWPmFA8ayKGYahhpdCAW97mg"}
```

I am getting this error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\receive.php on line 8
```

The line 8 refereed by the error is

```
foreach ($contendecoded as $each) {
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: can you share your code written before the foreach?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: you json not in array format like [{},{}], try with  '$contendecoded = array(json_decode($content))'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content of the file is NOT valid JSON.

You can refer this question (also answered by me)
[Decoding multiple JSON objects in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485288/decoding-multiple-json-objects-in-php/29485672#29485672)

```
function json_decode_multi($s, $assoc = false, $depth = 512, $options = 0) {
    if(substr($s, -1) == ',')
        $s = substr($s, 0, -1);
    return json_decode("[$s]", $assoc, $depth, $options);
}

$content =  file_get_contents('result.json');
$contendecoded = json_decode_multi($content);
print_r($contendecoded);
```

Comment: Your answer is working even without editing the JSON.  Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please post again your PHP code
2. JSON code not valid (need bracket / parenthesis)

Comment: You saved my day. I am following a tutorial and I somehow forgot to add [] brackets over my JSONfile. It's now working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a bracket pair in the JSON file, like this

```
[
{},
{}
]
```